# Where is the Red/Green Bar for unit-testing in IntelliJ 2018?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

The [manual for IntelliJ 2018](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tdd-with-intellij-idea.html) shows the usual Red/Green bar in the `Run` panel, as seen in this shot:

[image: screenshot of Run panel in IntelliJ with a Red bar for failed tests]

But in my IntelliJ Ultimate Edition version 2018.3.4, I see no such green or red bar, as seen in this screenshot from my computer:

[image: screenshot of Run panel in IntelliJ failing to show the expected red or green bar for unit-testing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## New feature: Red/Green bar disappears

I am working with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 Ultimate Edition (Build 183.5153.38) on a Windows 10. I would expect 2018.3.4 turn out the same considering the bar design.

The bar design and behavior is changed and the documentation seems not updated yet. It is shown just a **brief** moment before it is gone, as you can see in the following pictures.

Those unhappy with this new feature can vote for [issue ticket # IDEA-200548: *Keep showing the red / green bar when tests execution is finished*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200548).

green
[image]

red
[image]

And I see the checkmark icon after the test is ok

[image]

or a warning icon if the tests failed

[image]

Althoug I noticed, that sometimes the checkmark/warning icons are not shown. 
After rerun of the tests they appear again.

Comment: Please see/follow/comment usability problem issue already created at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200548

Comment: Hi @OlgaKlisho, Thanks for pointing out this issue on YouTrack. Good to know.